# Convert YYYYMMDD string to MM/DD/YYYY string

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a date that is stored as a string in the format YYYYDDMM.  I would like to display that value in a 'MM/DD/YYYY' format. I am programming in c#. The current code that I am using is as follows:

```
txtOC31.Text = dr["OC31"].ToString().Trim();
strOC31date = dr["OC31DATE"].ToString().Trim();
DateTime date31 = DateTime.Parse(strOC31date);
strOC31date = String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", date31);
```

However, I am getting an error because the YYYYMMDD string (strOC31date) is not being recognized as a valid datetime.

Comment: Please don't re-use variables. (In your case `strOC31date`) It's not very expensive to define new ones, especially if they are short strings.

Comment: The first four digits is the year.  Cut it out and parse it to an int.  The next two are the month.  Cut them out and parse it to an int.  The last two are the day.  Cut them out and parse to an int.  Use them to create a new DateTime.  It isn't much easier than that.

Comment: strOC31date = dr["OC31DATE"].ToString().Trim(), what is the content of this ?

Comment: Brandon,  the content of that field is a string YYYYMMDD; for example, 20120807

Answer (score 21, accepted):

DateTime.ParseExact with an example

```
string res = "20120708";
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(res, "yyyyddMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
```

Comment: In the very last line, the slash characters `/` in the format string will be translated to the date separator string of the current thread. If the culture of your current thread happens to have `/` as date separator, all is fine. But if you set the culture to e.g. `new CultureInfo("da-DK")` (Danish - Denmark) before the last line, then `/` will be transformed to `-`. To avoid this, one approach is to escape the slashes, i.e. say `d.ToString(@"MM\/dd\/yyyy")`.

Answer (score 11):

Use `ParseExact()` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)) when the string you are trying to parse is not in one of the standard formats.  This will allow you to parse a custom format and will be slightly more efficient (I compare them in a blog post [here](http://blackrabbitcoder.net/archive/2012/01/05/c.net-little-wonders-the-datetime-tryparse-and-parseexact-methods.aspx)).

```
DateTime date31 = DateTime.ParseExact(strOC31date, "yyyyMMdd", null);
```

Passing `null` for the format provider will default to `DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo` and is safe, but you probably want the invariant culture instead:

```
DateTime date31 = DateTime.ParseExact(strOC31date, "yyyyMMdd", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
```

Then your code will work.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `DateTime.Parse(strOC31date);` use `DateTime.ParseExact()` method, which takes format as one of the parameters.

Answer (score 3):

You want the method [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx).

```
DateTime date31 = DateTime.ParseExact(strOC31date, "yyyyddMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```